# Laravel passport personal access token are not expiring

Tags: laravel, token, access-token, laravel-passport, bearer-token

I'm trying to use the Laravel passport and I don't know if I found a bug or I'm missing something.

Login controller:

```
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
```

So I'm creating the token when an user login. On the database I see that the generated token has expires_at field: one week after so it's correct.
But if I change this value for an older date I can still use this token...

Laravel is simply ignoring this field? Why?

I did my research but I'm a bit confused... so many people says tokens don't expire or expire in 1 year. But then I found some posts with this snippet:

```
public function boot(){
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Passport::routes();
        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addHours(24));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));
}
```

I understand tokensExpireIn sets the expires_at field and refreshTokensExpireIn is for refresh this field everytime the user uses his token...

But if Laravel does not check this field anyway, it's no use.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the expiration date for personal tokens

```
 Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(1));
```

You will also need to regenerate your tokens as old will still have their expiration dates.

Comment: The problem is I want to verify that tokens are expiring... This line you posted just sets the expires_at field to 1 month later. I'm changing the expires_at field directly on the database setting for 1 year ago. But I can still use this token... Why? This is que question

Comment: ah ok. expires_at filed in your table will not be used when checking the expiration of the token. Each token created holds it's own expires_at. I would create a helper that checks whether users token expires_at < Carbon::now(). By default, in passport, personal token lifetime is set to 1 year.